# selenium bot working in no headless, not working in headless

Tags: python

trying to deal with the omegle bot i wrote, anyway if i put the headless options on, it returns me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vitto\Desktop\sb\tom.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\vitto\Desktop\sb\tom.py", line 45, in main
    getting()
  File "C:\Users\vitto\Desktop\sb\tom.py", line 17, in getting
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").click()
  File "C:\Users\vitto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\vitto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\vitto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\vitto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.164)
```

this is the code:

```
import sys
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
def main():
    chromeOptions=Options()
    chromeOptions.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe', options=chromeOptions)
    print(driver.get_window_size())
    time.sleep(2)
    def getting():
        driver.get("https://www.omegle.com")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").click()
    def ppaccept():
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div/p[1]/label/input").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div/p[2]/label/input").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div/p[3]/input").click()
    def mainloop():
        time.sleep(1.5)                       
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/textarea").send_keys("stuff")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/button").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/button").click()
        time.sleep(2.5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/button").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/button").click()
    def escape():
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/button").click()
        main()
    def main():
        while True:
            try:
                mainloop()
            except:
                try:
                   time.sleep(2)
                   escape()
                except:
                    sys.exit()
                
    getting()
    ppaccept()
    main()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

i have even tried to add to the code as i read this in a SO page and thsi solution worked for everybody, anyway, not for me:

```
chromeOptions.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
        chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```

but it still doesn't work, please help me, I really can't get what the problem is:

Comment: Try remove chromeOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")

Comment: same error, that's so weird